# Problema de variavel (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto de android Studio com kotlin e estou com o seguinte erro.

```
equal.setOnClickListener {
    try{
        val expressao = ExpressionBuilder(expressao.text.toString()).build()  

        val resultado = expressao.evaluate()
        val LongResult = resultado.toLong()

        if ( resultado == LongResult.toDouble()) {
            result.text = LongResult.toString()
        }else{
            result.text = resultado.toString()
        }

    }catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}
```

Especificamente nessa parte (expressao.text.toString()).build() , estou tendo problemas em adicionar expressao em expressao.text.toString.

Se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço desde já.

Comment: Esqueci de falar que está dando erro na compilação Unresolved reference: expressao

Comment: Na mesma linha em que você declara a variável `expressao`, você tenta utilizá-la, esse é o problema, por isso `Unresolved reference`.

Comment: Como eu resolveria tal problema então ? vc pode me mostrar com códigos ?

Comment: Não dá para alguém resolver esse problema para você, não tem contexto para saber o que você tenta fazer. Além disso, eu nunca usei `ExpressionBuilder`. O que posso orientar é que você precisa descobrir de onde pegar esse valor inicial para o `ExpressionBuilder`, porque claramente não deve ser de uma variável que ainda não foi declarada.

Comment: O pior q eu vi um cara fazendo exatamente o mesmo código no youtube, no dele dá tudo certo, mas no meu projeto dá esse erro.

Comment: E só deu esse erro quando tentei emular o app no android studio.